# django redirect view with parameter

Tags: python, django

In my App  I have the file urls.py that contains these rows:

```
...
path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
path('page/', views.page, name='page'),
....
```

and in my view.py file i have two view like this:

```
def home(request, value=0):
    print("value=", value)
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)


def page(request):
    if bad:
        return redirect(reverse('home'), value=1)
```

Is it possible to have the view function with a parameter (like the value in this case) and then use redirection from the page view passing some value based on the same condition like value=1, in this case, using the format described in the urls.py?
The code above always prints value=0 no matter what.

The only way I can think to do this is to use global variables which I would really like to avoid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need to add the parameter to the URL:

```
path('home/', views.home, name='home1'),
path('home/<int:value>/', views.home, name='home2'),
```

Then you need to pass the page in the redirect itself, together with the name of the view, you should not use `reverse(..)` here:

```
def page(request):
    if bad:
        return redirect('home2', value=1)
```

Comment: can't i just use ```path('home/', views.home, name='home'),``` in the urls.py file? do i need like two paths like in your example?
damn.. if that is the only way i think i will go for globals...

Comment: @idkasd: most webservers do not use something persistent other than databases (and some caching), it would imho a serious anti-pattern to use a global state (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil), and it would make the applications immediately unscalable. But no, in general the HTTP protocol is stateless, so that means that you should pass the data to the client to let it pass it back to you.